# Can i edit a function in a existing library like telephony manager?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want to edit the `getdeviceid` function of `telephony manager` to get the `IMEI` number even when Im on a `CDMA` network.

If anyone has any suggestions it will be helpful.

Comment: `telephony manager` is not a `library`. It is part of Android OS. You can edit it by flashing custom firmware into your device

Comment: Thanks.That can help me find the direction I need to go in.

Answer (score 2):

so many library's and classes can't be edited or changed , if you need do that , you must create your own class , copy and paste from original class to your class then edit or remove what you need , and anywhere you want use this class

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit all the libraries.

**You can do:**

Create your own class. After that you can or import or create this as a library.

If you need to edit any library just take the code and copy to your own class.

I hopen It will help you!